# What can I do with plist files outside of my app?

Tags: iphone, xml, plist

My iPhone app generates some very nice-looking plist files.  I can look at them through xcode 's plist editor and through any plain text editor when I just want the xml.  But can I do anything else with this data?  I tried importing the xml into a spreadsheet in NeoOffice, but it just showed the plain text.

All I'm asking is this:  Is there some sort of tool that I can use which will let me put the plist or xml data into a spreadsheet?  Or, what else can I do with my plist files?  What other programs are available?

Comment: What do you _want_ to do with the data?

Comment: Put it in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plist is just the default format when you save a NS data structure to disk.  Because it is based xml, it is easy to use for machines, but not necessarily for humans or spreadsheets.

Normally, you would configure your app to format and output your data in CSV (comma separated values) format and that is easily importable into any spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit them with Property List Editor which lives in /Developer/Applications/Utilities